# Tried to update field review.Review.name with a model instance, Use a value compatible with CharField

Tags: django

I was trying to add a review using the function i created and this error occured..

this is my **Review** model in **models.py** which is in the app **review**

```
class Review(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    place=models.ForeignKey(Place,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    location=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='place')
    photo=models.ImageField(upload_to='places')
    desc=models.TextField(max_length=3000,default=None)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50,default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.location
```

this is the **address**

```
href="{% url 'review:add_review' place.slug %}"
```

this is the **path**

```
from django.urls import path
from review import views

app_name="review"
urlpatterns = [
    path('add_review/<slug:pslug>',views.addreview,name='add_review'),
]
```

this is the **add review** function in **views.py**

```
def addreview(request,pslug):
    place=Place.objects.get(slug=pslug)
    if(request.method=="POST"):
        user=request.user
        title=request.POST['title']
        review=request.POST['review']
        photo=request.FILES['photo']
        review=Review.objects.create(title=title,desc=review,
                                     name=user,photo=photo,
                                     place=place)
        review.save()
        return placedetail(request,pslug)
    else:
        pass
    return render(request,'addreview.html')
```

what am i doing wrong and how can i fix it...

Answer (score 0):

In your model definition you state

```py
name=models.CharField(max_length=50,default=None)
```

That means that name has to be filled with [CharField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#charfield), meaning, it has to be a text.

And in your view, when you do

```py
review=Review.objects.create(title=title,desc=review,
                                     name=user,photo=photo,
                                     place=place)
```

You are trying to fill the "name"  field with `user`, which is a variable containing a user model instance (read above `user=request.user`)

If what you want to do is for "name" to be the author of the review you need to change your model (the name will be a [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) that points to the user model). Or you could fill "name" with a text, and that would also fix it (but I don't know exactly what is your goal).